# Azure DB not showing in Visual Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure

I have multiple DBs in Azure , today I installed Visual Studio express 
I connect to azure but none of my databases or websites appear ? when I right click on azure I see my subscriptions so I dont know why I can't see its associated web and databases

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: Which version of `Visual Studio Express`?